# Ubuntu VM not able to get an Ip address

Tags: 14.04, networking, virtualbox, dhcp

I have an ubuntu 14.04 VM in virtualbox on a Windows7 host. I was using NAT and it was working fine. Switched to bridged adapter and its no longer has internet access when i am on office wifi. Works fine on my home wifi though.

It can't get an ipv4 address and on doing

```
  sudo ifup eth0
```

it shows

> *No working leases in persistent database.*

My knowledge of ubuntu and networking in general is limited. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

When in bridged mode, for network purposes the virtual machine behaves exactly as if it were another physical machine on the network. So, in order to connect it to your office wifi, you need to ask your management about how to connect a new machine to it (depending on their policies, it may not even be possible).

Comment: That's a problem. Is there any other way so that other machines on the network can ping my VM? I am trying to use ubuntu as an openstack swift server, so its essential that other machines can connect to it.

Comment: Yes, you can setup port forwarding in VirtualBox, in much the same way you do it on a home router (in that case it is the host machine that acts as the router).

Comment: Does that mean it'll need NAT instead of bridged mode?

Comment: Yes, since apparently you can't use bridged mode on your network.

Comment: I am not entirely sure how to do that. I was under the assumption that with NAT, only the host will be a able to reach the VM and not other machines on the network?

Comment: That would be a separate question. :)